# Implicit view parameter

Tags: scala, implicit

I'm following the Twitter Scala school tutorial, and I've run into an issue. In the section for implicit views, under advanced types [here](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html), it states that methods can ask for specific kinds of evidence for a type.

It lists 3 of these kinds of evidence -

```
A =:= B A must be equal to B
A <:< B A must be a subtype of B
A <%< B A must be viewable as B
```

However, the code I write has a syntax error when I try the third kind.

This is my code

```
class ContainerTwo[A](value : A) {
  // A must be a subtype of Int
  def addIt(implicit evidence : A <:< Int) = 123 + value
  // A must be a viewable as a String
  def printIt(implicit evidence : A <%< String) = println(evidence)  // This line reports an error at <%< - "Cannot resolve symbol <%<"
  // A must be a subtype of a String 
  def doSomethingWithAString(implicit evidence : A <:< String) = println(evidence)
```

}

I'm using Scala 2.10. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, the tutorial is wrong, or if Scala has changed since the time that the tutorial was written.

Comment: Please always include the *actual* error, don't just describe it briefly as "reports a syntax error".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<%<` was deprecated and presumably now removed, which is why you see an error (it is not a syntax error). You can achieve the same thing using `=>`, because a view is essentially an implicit function instance:

```
def printIt(implicit evidence : A => String) = println(evidence(value))
```

Note that since `println` takes an argument of type `Any`, the function probably won't be applied unless you do it explicitly. If you had used a method that required a `String`, then the compiler would look for the implicit.

Comment: Thanks. println() was just a placeholder for me, I didn't plan on doing anything with it.